# jQuery reload image depending on variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have two images img0.png and img1.png. I want to reload image depending on bool variable.
I tried
`<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false }); 
        setInterval(function() {
            d = new Date();
            $("#abc1").attr("src", "images/img:="status":.png?"+d.getTime());
        },1000);
    });
</script>`

where :="status": is bool variable I get from PLC.

It is necessary to reload whole page to refresh image when bool variable changes. Is it possible to reload it without refresh?

EDIT:

Problem solved.

```
setInterval(function() {
    $.get("variable.htm", function(result){
        $("#abc1").attr("src", "images/img" + result + ".png");
        });
},1000);
```

where variable.htm contains :="status": only.
Thanks for comments.

Comment: No. Yes. What's the problem with the code you've shown? Have you done some debugging to see whether your status var is updating?

Comment: After I changed status variable(from 0 to 1), image didn't change. I had to refresh whole page to see new image(which is img1.png).

Comment: What is this? `"images/img:="status":.png?"`

Comment: Seems to work fine: http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/b8qw859p/

Comment: Demo updated to show status value.